# Use WildCard certificate in Azure FrontDoor

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-front-door

We have an issue importing wildcard certificates from Auzre KeyVault in Azure FronDoor. We import certificates from Azure KeyVault to setup custom domain https in our frontend/domains which have app services behind them. It works like charm if we use single domain certificates but if we try to import a wildcard certificate we get the following error:

"**Failed to update the custom https configuration**

Failed to update the custom https configuration for the frontend host 'frontendhostname'. Error: The certificate doesn't include the hostname to be secured."

Since we must use wildcard certificates for some of our apps on our subdomains, we are forced to remove rules regarding them from Azure FrontDoor and setup custom domains and import wildcard certificate directly on those app services unfortunately.

So the question is that is there any problem with importing wildcard certificates on Azure FrontDoor? If so, is there any workaround?

Please note that both abovementioned app services and Front Door has the same access level (Role) on KeyVault.

Cheers

Comment: I wonder the same. Always get the error:
Failed to update the custom https configuration for the frontend host 'my-domain.com'. Error: The certificate doesn't include the hostname to be secured.

Comment: seems it was my fault and the domain I tried to use the certificate wasn't in the wildcard pattern.
It is supported by Azure https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-wildcard-domain?pivots=front-door-standard-premium